# dplyr: Mutate column base on match string of column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe ds:

```
sample
16LM1DNA
16M1DNA
```

And I would like to create a new column base on LM or M in the sample names:

I have this code:

```
ds %>% 
mutate(group = case_when( 
matches(sample, "\\d+LMd+") ~ "LM",
matches(sample, "\\d+Md+") ~ "M"
))
```

But it doesn't work.

Best

Comment: In poor old, base R, you could do `dat$group <- sub("\\d+([LM]+).*", "\\1", dat$sample)`.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got it this way:

```
ds %>% 
mutate(group = case_when( 
grepl("\\d+LMd+",sample ) ~ "LM",
grepl("\\d+Md+", sample) ~ "M"
))
```

Comment: Taking into account your answers I use grep, then combine it with dplyr case_when

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a regex based solution along a different line, using `gsub` and `grep`, e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(sample=c('16LM1DNA', '16M1DNA', 'STUFF'))

ind <- grep("\\d+([A-Za-z]+).*", df$sample, value=FALSE)
df$label <- gsub('\\d+([A-Za-z]+).*', '\\1', df$sample)
df$label[-ind] <- ""
df

    sample label
1 16LM1DNA    LM
2  16M1DNA     M
3    STUFF
```

## Demo

The call to `grep` is not really the meat and potatoes of the answer, but is needed to handle the edge case where the pattern in `gsub` matches nothing.  By default, `gsub` returns the entire string being matched, whereas I thought empty string would make more sense as a label in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` in base-R could help

```
> newdf <- data.frame(sample = c(
+                            '16LM1DNA',
+                            '16M1DNA'))
> 
> newdf$group <- ifelse(grepl('LM1',newdf$sample),'LM',
+                       ifelse(grepl('M1',newdf$sample),'M1',NA))
> 
> 
> newdf
    sample group
1 16LM1DNA    LM
2  16M1DNA    M1
>
```

Comment: OK, but this hard codes the two labels from the OP.  Using a regex would be more flexible because we could potentially capture _any_ label.